# Error al conectar mongodb en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Estoy empezando a crear mi base de datos y enlazarla con mi servidor, pero no me funciona.

**Error**

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node src/indexE.js`

(node:3892) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3892) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.

Server on port 3000

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:562:14
    at E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:995:11
    at E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:32:7
    at callback (E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:280:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\usuarios\alumno\Escritorio\MERN\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:310:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro: `Error: Cannot find module './database.js'`, no se puede encontrar el módulo `database.js`, revisa que existe y está en la ruta correcta.

Comment: SI EXISTE  AHORA LE SACO CAP Y TE MUESTRO

Comment: [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/451807/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: ahora? esta bien asi?

Comment: ahi dice que no se pudo conectar a la base de daatos, verifica tu cadena de conexion, ademas agregalo a la pregunta

Comment: no entendi como la cadena de conexion

Comment: La `Uri`, para que me llegue notificación mencioname @Christian

Comment: gracias @Christian ya lo pude solucionar

Comment: Lee el error, te dice exactamente qué pasa y qué hacer:

(node:3892) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.